# Chef, related path from cookbook to file storage

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Is it possibile to get absolute path to cookbook directory(I don't need path to cache).

What I want to do?
My structure:

```
Chef
    -Cookbooks(tomcat, java, etc.)
    -Profiles(json files with configs)
    -Resources(zip files with programs)
    runScript0.bat
    runScript1.bat
    ....
```

How can I get path to Resources folder from recipes, I need to get files from this folder w/o hardcodded path. Of course I can download programs from svn/git, but I need this option too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure you describe is not inside a cookbook so those files do not exist as far as Chef is concerned. Even inside a cookbook, you need to use a `cookbook_file` or `remote_directory` resource to write to a known place first.